# Error in the Merge Function(Merge Sort)

Tags: c, sorting, merge

I am trying to implement the merge sort algorithm as mentioned in the algorithms book by CLRS. I have come up with the following code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void merge_sort(int *arr,int start_index,int end_index);
void merge(int *arr,int start_index,int middle_index,int end_index);

int main(){

int arr[]={5,2,1,6,0,3,3,4}; //8 elements last index 7
int i;
printf("Before sorting.\n");
for(i=0;i<8;i++)
printf("%d,",arr[i]);
merge_sort(arr,0,7);
printf("\nAfter sorting.\n");
for(i=0;i<8;i++)
printf("%d,",arr[i]);

return 0;}

void merge_sort(int *arr,int start_index,int end_index){
    int middle_index;
    if(start_index<end_index)
    {
        middle_index=(start_index+end_index)/2;
        merge_sort(arr,start_index,middle_index);
        merge_sort(arr,(middle_index+1),end_index);
        merge(arr,start_index,middle_index,end_index);
    }

}

void merge(int *arr, int start_index,int middle_index, int end_index){

    int n1,n2,i,l,m;
    n1=middle_index-start_index+1;
    n2=end_index-middle_index;
    int sub_arr1[n1+1],sub_arr2[n2+1];
    for(i=0;i<=(n1-1);i++)
        sub_arr1[i]=arr[i];
     for(i=0;i<=(n2-1);i++)
        sub_arr2[i]=arr[middle_index+1+i];

    sub_arr1[n1]=100;
    sub_arr2[n2]=100;
        l=0,m=0;
    for(i=0;i<=end_index;i++){


        if(sub_arr1[l]<sub_arr2[m])
        {arr[i]=sub_arr1[l];
        l=l+1;}
        else
         {arr[i]=sub_arr2[m];
        m=m+1;}

    }}
There seems to be some error in the merge function due to which I am getting an erroneous output which is as follows.

Before sorting.
5,2,1,6,0,3,3,4,
After sorting.
2,4,100,-1076668400,2,4,100,7,
RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 0ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

Since the numbers that I am sorting with this method are small, I have used 100 as a sentinel value. Can that be a possible source of error? Any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the error in my merge function. But I'm getting a wrong output with some garbage values.

Comment: @Gangadhar I could not edit my question for some reason and hence this question and moreover the suggestions made on the previous questions didn't work.

Comment: say them with the help of comments. still if you can't convey through comments. then EDIT your post and at the down add EDIT rather changing asked one.asking same question here not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your merge function: you are ignoring start_index. These lines:

```
for(i=0;i<=(n1-1);i++)
    sub_arr1[i]=arr[i];
```

Should be replaced by:

```
for(i=0;i<=(n1-1);i++)
    sub_arr1[i]=arr[start_index+i];
```

And the last for loop, should, instead, start with i = start_index:

```
for (i=start_index;i<=end_index;i++) { /* ... */ }
```

I improved indentation a little bit. Here's the final working version of merge():

```
void merge(int *arr, int start_index,int middle_index, int end_index) {
    int n1,n2,i,l,m;
    n1=middle_index-start_index+1;
    n2=end_index-middle_index;
    int sub_arr1[n1+1],sub_arr2[n2+1];
    for (i=0;i<=(n1-1);i++)
        sub_arr1[i]=arr[start_index+i];
     for (i=0;i<=(n2-1);i++)
        sub_arr2[i]=arr[middle_index+1+i];
    sub_arr1[n1]=100;
    sub_arr2[n2]=100;
    l=0,m=0;
    for (i=start_index;i<=end_index;i++) {
        if(sub_arr1[l]<sub_arr2[m]) {
            arr[i]=sub_arr1[l];
            l=l+1;
        }
        else {
            arr[i]=sub_arr2[m];
            m=m+1;
        }
    }
}
```

Tested and working.